# Will_paginate and waypoint duplicates

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, will-paginate, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

I'm using the will_paginate gem and jQuery waypoint. Works nicely when it gets the 2nd page but then when it gets the 3rd page it appends it twice.

Here's the code:

```
  $(".pagination .next_page").waypoint ->
      url = $(this).attr('href')
      $.getJSON url, (data) ->
        $(".pagination").remove()
        $(".items_container").append data.items
```

I've tried adding `.on "waypoint", ->` and `off().on "waypoint" ->`, but it still appends the results twice..

Any ideas?

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside that function and see what's calling it each time.

Comment: It's a good call, I forgot about that feature. So I've set a breakpoint and I follow the the function step by step, but unfortunately I don't really know how what to look for.. It lists waypoint twice in the 'call stack'...

Comment: OK, now breakpoint and check if `$(".pagination .next_page").waypoint ->` is being called twice. you may accidentally be assigning the same handler more than once.

Comment: Where will I see if it is? Sorry I have little experience in doing this...

Comment: Find the line in the your JS output that looks like `$(".pagination .next_page").waypoint(function......` and put a breakpoint on it. run the app like normal and scroll on down the page. Count how many times you have to resume the debugger. If your code hits that same line twice, then you have an error in your program that's causing the handler to be assigned twice.

Comment: Yeah it does ... It comes back to it a second time.. So from here I just go through my code or is there anything I can do with the debugger? Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: go through your code carefully. Using a debugger get it to break on the second time it calls that function, then inspect the call stack. see if you can catch what is making that second call.

Comment: It turned out that the problem was something else. I was appending a partial into the $(".items_container"), but I completely forgot that inside the partial was the $(".items_container") again. So it duplicated the container which created duplicates, but not duplicate events. Anyway, thanks so much for your patience and help. Moral of the story is that I really need more practise at debugging Javascript, especially when such useful tools exist, tools that every developer should know how to use.